# Java Upgrades cause Tomcat setenv.sh file to be out of date

Tags: java, tomcat

We set our Java_home for Tomcat in a setenv.sh file like so JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-1.el7_9.x86_64

The issue is the openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-1.el7_9.x86_64 directory changes slightly when they push updates.  Any answers?

Comment: Is there a soft link in `/usr/lib/jvm` that is more generic?  I have a different O/S than you but I have a soft link that doesn't change when the version of Java is updated.

Comment: i think there may be will try - also I removed Java 8 from alternatives so there is only 1 java.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.